# javafx 8 Parallel Transitions for two nodes

Tags: multithreading, animation, javafx, path

I have two Paths p1 and p2 with two Path Transitions animP1 and animP2 I have placed the two Path Transitions in a Parallel Transition pt When I call the pt play the error is Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
How can I over come this ERROR?
I am trying to move two different nodes over two different paths at the same time

```
        p1 = new Path(new MoveTo(340, 360),
            new HLineTo(260),
            new VLineTo(500),
            new HLineTo(340),
            new VLineTo(700),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(580),
            new HLineTo(120),
            new VLineTo(240),
            new HLineTo(340),
            new VLineTo(40),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(180),
            new HLineTo(160),
            new VLineTo(80)
            );

    p1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    p1.setStrokeWidth(4);

    //Shape union = Shape.union(p2, p1);
    //p1.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);//do this onLOAD
    Duration numSECP1 = Duration.valueOf("10.0s");
    animP1 = new PathTransition(numSECP1,p1,c);
    animP1.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
    animP1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    animP1.setAutoReverse(true);
    animP1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    Duration numSECP2 = Duration.valueOf("10.0s");
    animP2 = new PathTransition(numSECP2,p2,c2);
    animP2.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
    animP2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    animP2.setAutoReverse(true);
    animP2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
    p2 = new Path(new MoveTo(680,40),
            new VLineTo(700),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(40),
            new HLineTo(680)
            );
    p2.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    p2.setStrokeWidth(4);
    pt = new ParallelTransition();
    pt.setCycleCount(PathTransition.INDEFINITE);
    pt.getChildren().addAll(animP1,animP2);
```

Comment: When you get an exception that you would like somebody to troubleshoot, you should include a stack trace, code that compiles to line numbers that correspond to the stack trace and an indication in your question of which line in your code is reported by the stack trace as the cause of your exception.  Often, provision of an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) aids in the resolution of such questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to play multiplet PathTransitions at the same time on separate nodes all that needs to be done is call play() on both of them.

A ParallelTransition is for performing multiple transitions on a single node, for example a FadeTransition and a PathTransition.

The following executes two PathTransitions simultaneously:

```
import javafx.animation.PathTransition;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class JavaFXApplication extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {       

    StackPane root = new StackPane();        
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 700, 650);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
    // Create Rectangles
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
    rect.setArcHeight(50);
    rect.setArcWidth(50);
    rect.setFill(Color.VIOLET);
    Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle (100, 40, 100, 100);
    rect2.setArcHeight(50);
    rect2.setArcWidth(50);
    rect2.setFill(Color.RED);

    // Add rectangles to scene
    root.getChildren().addAll(rect, rect2);

    // Create first Path
    Path path = new Path();
    path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(20,20));
    path.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(380, 0, 380, 120, 200, 120));
    PathTransition pathTransition = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
    pathTransition.setNode(rect);
    pathTransition.setPath(path);
    // Create second Path
    Path path2 = new Path();
    path2.getElements().add(new MoveTo(180,30));
    path2.getElements().add(new CubicCurveTo(180, 0, 380, 120, 200, 120));
    PathTransition pathTransition2 = new PathTransition();
    pathTransition2.setDuration(Duration.millis(10000));
    pathTransition2.setNode(rect2);
    pathTransition2.setPath(path2);
    pathTransition2.setAutoReverse(true);

   // Play both transitions
   pathTransition.play();
   pathTransition2.play();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Actually, you can perform parallel transitions on different nodes.  The [ParallelTransition node property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/ParallelTransition.html#nodeProperty), states: "This Node is used in all child Transitions, that do not define a target Node themselves.", so you could specify (different) nodes in the child transitions and no node in the parallel transition if you wished.  I'm not saying it should be done that way, just that it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

@James_Duh @Josh Wein The reason this code will not run is you are trying to use a variable before it has been declared correct order below. A simple mistake we have all made. you are trying to use p2 before it was created

```
    p1 = new Path(new MoveTo(400, 360),
            new HLineTo(240),
            new VLineTo(500),
            new HLineTo(340),
            new VLineTo(680),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(560),
            new HLineTo(120),
            new VLineTo(240),
            new HLineTo(360),
            new VLineTo(40),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(180),
            new HLineTo(180),
            new VLineTo(100)
            );

    p1.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    p1.setStrokeWidth(4);

    p2 = new Path(new MoveTo(800,40),
            new VLineTo(680),
            new HLineTo(40),
            new VLineTo(40),
            new HLineTo(800)
            );

    p2.setStroke(Color.YELLOW);
    p2.setStrokeWidth(4);
        Duration numSECP1 = Duration.valueOf("6.5s");//was 8.5
    //animP1 = new PathTransition(numSECP1,s1,cp1);
    animP1 = new PathTransition(numSECP1, p1, cp1);
    animP1.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
    animP1.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    animP1.setDelay(Duration.seconds(4.5));
    animP1.setAutoReverse(true);
    animP1.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);

    Duration numSECP2 = Duration.valueOf("6.5s");//was 8.5
    animP2 = new PathTransition(numSECP2,p2,cp2);
    animP2.setOrientation(OrientationType.NONE);
    animP2.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);
    //animP2.setDelay(Duration.seconds(1));
    animP2.setAutoReverse(true);
    animP2.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
```